# Python: I want to fill the null values only where the whole row is null

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a Data frame that looks like:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5

A       B       C       D       E
B       X       Y       null    null
null    null    null    null    null
I       B       W       E       R
```

Since third row has all the null values, I want to fill one value in the third row.
The final Data frame should look like:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5

A       B       C       D       E
B       X       Y       null    null
xyz     null    null    null    null
I       B       W       E       R
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for set `Col1` column by mask created by [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) and [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for test all `True`
s per row:

```
df.loc[df.isna().all(axis=1), 'Col1'] = 'xyz'
print (df)
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
0    A    B    C    D    E
1    B    X    Y  NaN  NaN
2  xyz  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3    I    B    W    E    R
```

For fill first column:

```
df.iloc[df.isna().all(axis=1).values, 0] = 'xyz'
```